# TFS fail to build with "sqlite3\db.lock' because it is being used by another process"

Tags: tfs

We have switched from the old xaml-build definitions to the new build definitions in TFS 2017. When we try to build the project it fails with the following error:

---

```
Starting: Build
******************************************************************************
Current agent version: '2.117.2'
******************************************************************************
Starting: Initialize Job
******************************************************************************
Prepare build directory.
One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The process cannot access the file 'E:\agent builds\agent1\1\s\Server\.vs\Server\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock' because it is being used by another process.)) (The process cannot access the file 'E:\agent builds\agent1\1\s\Server\.vs\Server\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock' because it is being used by another process.)
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Initialize Job
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Build
******************************************************************************
```

Why is it locking an sqlite database when building? What can be configured wrong to cause this?

Answer (score 3):

I found out that one of our developers built the project manually in Visual Studio 2017 on the TFS server recently, and even if VS was closed the files seems to be locked by it. A reboot of the TFS server solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, TFS Server reboot fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not checking in files and folders that you don't need (i.e. bin, obj,  and .vs folders). In order to exclude such things, you might want use a .tfignore file if you're using TFVC or a .gitignore file if you're using git.

Comment: Thanks for responding! These files are not part of the check-in. I found out that one of our developers built the project manually in Visual Studio 2017 on the TFS server recently, and event if vs is closed the files seems to be locked by it. A reboot of the TFS server solved the issue. Will put this as answer after the min 2 days wait.

Answer (score 0):

.vs and the files in it should not checked into TFS.